# Regex to remove all whitespace except around keywords and between quotes

Tags: java, regex

I want to:

1. remove all whitespaces unless it's right before or after (0-1 space before and 0-1 after) the predefined keywords (for example: and, or, if then we leave the spaces in " and " or " and" or "and " unchanged)
2. ignore everything between quotes

I've tried many patterns. The closest I've come up with is pretty close, but it still removes the space after keywords, which I'm trying to avoid.

regex:

```
\s(?!and|or|if)(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Test String:

```
            if    (ans(this) >= ans({1,2})  and (cond({3,4})  or ans(this) <= ans({5,6})), 7, 8)  and {111} > {222}  or ans(this) = "hello    my friend and  or  " and(cond({1,2}) $1 123
```

Ideal result:

```
 if (ans(this)>=ans({1,2}) and (cond({3,4}) or ans(this)<=ans({5,6})),7,8) and {111}>{222} or ans(this)="hello    my friend and  or  " and(cond({1,2})$1123
```

I then can use `str = str.replaceAll` in java to remove those whitespaces. I don't mind doing multiple steps to get to the result, but I am not familiar with regex so kinda stuck.

any help would be appreciated!

Note: I edited the result. Sorry about that. For the space around keywords: shrunk to 1 if there are spaces. Either leave it or add 1 space if it's 0 (I just don't want "or ans" becomes "orans", but "and(cond" becomes "and (cond)" is fine (shrink to 1 space before and 1 space after if exists). Ignore everything between quotes.

Comment: Sometimes Regex's are simply not the best solution;  they become complex, fragile, and unmaintainable - for example, would you expect it to handle escaped-quotes, like `ans(this) = "this quote \" is escaped"` ?   Is there any reason you want Regex rather than code parsing ?

Comment: Your question's expected result is not clear. Can you please fix your ideal result part.

Comment: Yuk....but it seems to do something similar to the desired output: `str = str.replaceAll("\\s+(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "").replaceAll("if(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", "if ").replaceAll("and(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", " and ").replaceAll("or(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", " or ");`.

Comment: So the whitespaces around `"..."` must be removed, right? Leading/trailing whitespace must be removed? The inner spaces should be shrunk to a single space? And `ans({4,6})` -> `ans({1,2})` is not actually what you expect, right? You expect the numbers to stay, right?

Comment: No, your ideal result can be achieved without explanation why some whitespace around keywords is shrunk and some is not. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I edited the result. Sorry about that. The number should stay the same.

For the space around keywords: shrunk to 1 if there are spaces. Either leave it or add 1 space if it's 0 (I just don't want "or ans" becomes "orans", but "and(cond" becomes "and (cond)" is fine (shrink to 1 space before and 1 space after). Ignore everything between quotes.

Comment: Please try https://ideone.com/C4RIzL. I had a bit different solution before your last edit, and it might still be good  but this one is much simpler. If it does not work please add more test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, it seems to work very well for my application. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
String example = "            if    (ans(this) >= ans({1,2})  and (cond({3,4})  or ans(this) <= ans({5,6})), 7, 8)  and {111} > {222}  or ans(this) = \"hello    my friend and  or  \" and(cond({1,2}) $1 123    ";
String rx = "\\s*\\b(and|or|if)\\b\\s*|(\"[^\"]*\")|(\\s+)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(rx).matcher(example);
example = m.replaceAll(r -> r.group(3) != null ? "" : r.group(2) != null ? r.group(2) : " " + r.group(1) + " ").trim();
System.out.println( example );
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/HzYbwR).

The pattern matches

- `\s*\b(and|or|if)\b\s*` - 0+ whitespaces, word boundary, Group 1: `and`, `or`, `if`, word boundary and then 0+ whitespaces
- `|`  - or
- `(\"[^\"]*\")` - Group 2: `"`, any 0+ chars other than `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `(\s+)` - Group 3: 1+ whitespaces.

If Group 3 matches, they are removed, if Group 2 matches, it is put back into the result and if Group 1 matches, it is wrapped with spaces and pasted back. The whole result is `.trim()`ed.

Answer (score 2):

You make an intelligent use of capturing groups. The general idea here would be

```
match_this|or_this|or_even_this|(but_capture_this)
```

In terms of a regular expression this could be

```
(?:(?:\s+(?:and|or|if)\s+)|"[^"]+")|(\s+)
```

You'd then need to replace the match only if the first capturing group is not empty.

---

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/gfhfUf/1/) (with `(*SKIP*)(*FAIL)` which serves the same purpose).